# Hosting WPF usercontrol in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Is there any toolbox item or control or any other way by which I can host a wpf usercontrol inside an asp.net web site? I can host wpf inside win form but I want it done in asp.net.

Comment: XBAP/Silverlight - web technologies are completely different from desktop ones - I wouldn't even bother pursuing this

Answer (score 0):

You can't host a WPF usercontrol inside any website. The closest thing is the use of Silverlight, which runs in a browser. But Silverlight isn't maitained and developed anymore...